# Requiring an annotation field when some other field has a specific value

Tags: java, spring, annotations, annotation-processing

If I have a field annotation defined as such:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface  LineField {
    public int at();
    public int length();
    public String literal() default "[unassigned]";
    public boolean isId() default false;

}
```

Is it possible in the api itself to have 'literal' be non-optional when  'isId' is set as true,

example :

```
//Valid
    @LineField(at = 0, length = 1, isId = true, literal = "6")
    private String recordTypeCode;

//Invalid
      @LineField(at = 0, length = 1, isId = true)
    private String recordTypeCode;
```

Comment: You can set isId as required. This will eliminate errors. It is not difficult to set an additional parameter in the annotation.

Comment: yeah that does make sense, it's only a little tedious as there are many fields in a typical record, most of them are non-id fields

Comment: Can you have `isId` at `false` while having a `literal` value ? e.g; `@LineField(at = 0, length = 1, isId = false, literal = "42")` ?